# Best spell checking solution for Texpad?

Tags: spelling, texpad

I realize versions of this question have been asked numerous times, but looking through those I have not found any recent answers, or any completely satisfying ones. I'm curious what solutions people use for spell checking their TeX documents, and specifically on Texpad (which is what I use). At the moment, I basically rely on the continuous checker, which is not a good solution since it's very easy to miss things. I tried cocoAspell before, so as to be able to use just the Spelling and Grammar pane, but it always seemed not to work well. Any other ideas?